# Is there a dplyr-way of writing summarise SQL queries with conditions?

Tags: sql, r, database, postgresql, dplyr

I have some data in a SQL Database and established a connection via RStudio.
So i reference my data with tbl():

```
data = tibble(id = c(65000, 65000, 65000, 65005, 65005, 65005, 65010, 65010, 65010), stock = c(12, 7, -4, 54, 51, 46, 183, 89, -1), week = c(43,44,45,43,44,45,43,44,45))

> tbl(connection, "data")
# Source:   table<data> [?? x 3]
# Database: postgres 13.0.0 [postgres@localhost:5432/postgres]
     id stock  week
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 65000    12    43
2 65000     7    44
3 65000    -4    45
4 65005    54    43
5 65005    51    44
6 65005    46    45
7 65010   183    43
8 65010    89    44
9 65010    -1    45
```

Since iam not familiar with SQL very much i stick to dyplr queries. I would like to calculate the ratio of items (id) available in a given week, and try the following:

```
tbl(connection, "data")%>%summarise(r=mean(stock>0))
```

However i get the message `INT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` and it seems SQL cannot translate this dplyr syntax. So my question is what would be the dplyr way to achive my intention that should look like this:

```
data%>%group_by(week)%>%summarise(r=mean(stock>0))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   week     r
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    43 1    
2    44 1    
3    45 0.333
```

I definitely want to push this computation to the database since the amount of data is to huge. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R automatically converts the `logical` `TRUE`/`FALSE` into `1` and `0` respectively. For `dbplyr`, you need to do it explicitly with `ifelse`.

```
tbl(connection, data) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(r = mean(ifelse(stock > 0, 1, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you may try this:

```
select week, avg(case when stock > 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS r
from data
where stock > 0
group by week
```